# Create a batch script to use sendemail.exe in Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to create a little batch script to run via task scheduler but running into an issue with the multiple PDF files in the same directory.

My aim is:

1. map the remote NAS (this is to take load off the server, and as a backup)
2. move the existing PDFs into an archive folder (of the same directory) except newest 2 files
3. clean the archive to delete the oldest n
4. email the attachments to my address
5. unmount the NAS

---

The code so far:

```
:: delete the old mapping
NET USE A: /DELETE

:: map the backup location
NET USE A: \\NAS\Share\BU

:: set the time and date YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.UUU
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%%ldt:~4,2%%ldt:~6,2%-%ldt:~8,2%%ldt:~10,2%%ldt:~12,6%

:: archive older than the last one - local
pushd "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Database Backups"
echo :: Move these files  ::
echo ------------------------
for /f "skip=2 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.pdf') do MOVE "%%F" ".\archive"

:: clean the archive folder - local
echo :: Delete these files ::
echo ------------------------
pushd "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Database Backups\archive"
for /f "skip=46 eol=: delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /o-d /b /s *.pdf') do del "%%a"

:: go to export directory
cd "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Database Backups"

:: copy to NAS
copy /b *.pdf "\\NAS\Share\BU\File_PDF_BU_%ldt%.pdf"

:: archive older than the last one - remotely
pushd "A:\"
echo :: Move these files  ::
echo ------------------------
for /f "skip=2 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.pdf') do MOVE "%%F" "A:\archive"

:: delete old archives - remotely
echo :: Delete these files ::
echo ------------------------
pushd "A:\archive"
for /f "skip=46 eol=: delims=" %%b in ('dir /a-d /o-d /b /s *.pdf') do del "%%b"

:: send confirmation email
"C:\Program Files\sendEmail\sendEmail.exe" -o -f "FromServer" -t me@domain.ltd -a "\\NAS\Share\BU\File_PDF_BU_%ldt%.pdf" -s smtp.domain.ltd:25 -u "Subject: %ldt%" -m Script successfully run"

:: wait 60 seconds
TIMEOUT /T 60

:: delete the old mapping
NET USE A: /DELETE /Y

:: exit the script
exit
```

---

At the moment, I am having issues with the files being generated from the programme itself. I am receiving two files `Database01_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSUUUU.pdf` and `Database02_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSUUUU.pdf` in the `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Database Backups` folder. So when I am copying, there is no way to limit to the two PDFs.

Is there a way to move the current two files in the root folder into a folder, then move that into the `archive` folder. Then keep the most recent 11 folders (runs for 12 hours - 11 + 1 in root) in the archive folder. And attach the folder to the `sendemail.exe`?

Comment: Are the files named like `Database01_YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSUUUU.pdf` being generated by some other program? If so, what is the use of `ldt` as the date time could be reused from the filename. Seems that `ltd` containing a single constant value is no good for copying multiple files based on wildcard. I rewrote some of your code, though now I see `ltd` as obsolete, or perhaps I misunderstand the actual process.

Comment: @michael_heath those names are being generated from another programme on its output - but have since changed it to be `Database0#_YYYYMMDD-HHMM.pdf`. `%ltd%` is used in the email to notify what time the script ran/sent the email - my mistake to not remove it. I have solved it as it was a limitation to `sendEmail.exe` I am using `cMail.exe` as it has a wildcard feature for them.

Comment: Thanks for info, I guess I was on the right path. I posted my answer for ideas for you rather than deleting it. `cMail` seems better with the wildcard support helps to keep the code simple. Just watch using `dir` with `/s` while ordering by date as `dir` does it by directory, so you may not necessarily be deleting the latest PDFs if exist in multiple directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with changing from `sendEmail.exe` to `cMail.exe`:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: set the time and date YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.UUU
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%%ldt:~4,2%%ldt:~6,2%-%ldt:~8,2%%ldt:~10,2%%ldt:~12,6%

:: map the backup location
NET USE A: \\NAS\SHARE\DB_BU

:: archive the old files - local
pushd "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Database Backups/"
for /f "skip=2 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.pdf') do MOVE "%%F" ".\archive"

:: clean the archive folder - local
pushd "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Database Backups/archive/"
for /f "skip=22 eol=: delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /o-d /b /s *.pdf') do DEL "%%a"

:: go to export directory
cd "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Database Backups"

:: copy PDFs to A: drive
copy /b "*.pdf" "A:/"

:: archive the old files - local
pushd "A:/"
for /f "skip=2 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.pdf') do MOVE "%%F" ".\archive"

:: clean the archive folder - local
pushd "A:/archive/"
for /f "skip=22 eol=: delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /o-d /b /s *.pdf') do DEL "%%a"

:: send confirmation email
"C:\Program Files\cMail\CMail.exe" -host:smtp.domain.ltd:25 -from:backup@domain.ltd -to:me@domain.ltd -awild:"A:\Database_*.pdf" "-subject:PDF backup: %ldt%" "-body:Backup script successfully run at %ldt%\nPlease find attached database documents\n\nThis is automated"

:: wait 60 seconds
TIMEOUT /T 60

:: delete the old mapping
NET USE A: /DELETE /Y

:: exit the script
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "attachments=%=do_not_modify=%"
set "db_backups_dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Database Backups"
set "nas_dir=\\NAS\Share\BU"
set "email=C:\Program Files\sendEmail\sendEmail.exe"

rem Push initial dir to connect drive
pushd "%nas_dir%" || exit /b 1

rem Set the time and date YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSUUUU
set "ldt="
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%I in (
    `wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>nul`
) do if ".%%~I." == ".LocalDateTime." set "ldt=%%~J"
if not defined ldt popd & exit /b 2
set "ldt=%ldt:~0,8%-%ldt:~8,6%%ldt:~15,4%

rem Archive older than the last one and delete old archives - local
call :process_files "%db_backups_dir%" "%nas_dir%"

rem Archive older than the last one and delete old archives - remote
call :process_files "%nas_dir%"

rem Pop initial dir to disconnect drive
popd

rem Send confirmation email
if not defined attachments exit /b 3
echo(%attachments%| find "|" && exit /b 4

echo "%email%" -o -f "FromServer" -t me@domain.ltd -a %attachments% ^
 -s smtp.domain.ltd:25 -u "Subject: %ldt%" -m Script successfully run"

exit /b 0

:process_files  target, destination
rem :process_files "%~1" "%~2"
setlocal
if "%~1" == "" exit /b 1
pushd "%~1" || exit /b 2
echo cd   "%~1"

set "copy_file="
set "copied_file_1="
set "copied_file_2="

if not exist "archive" md "archive"

rem Copy files from local to remote and move files to archive
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /o-d *.pdf 2^>nul') do (
    if defined copied_file_1 if defined copied_file_2 (
        echo move "%%~nxA" "archive\"
        move "%%~A" "archive\" >nul
    )

    if not defined copied_file_1 (
        set "copy_file=y"
    ) else if not defined copied_file_2 (
        set "copy_file=y"
    )

    if defined copy_file (
        set "copy_file="

        if not "%~2" == "" (
            for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
                echo copy "%%~A" "%~2\File_PDF_BU_%%~C.pdf"
                copy /b "%%~A" "%~2\File_PDF_BU_%%~C.pdf" >nul

                if not defined copied_file_1 (
                    set "copied_file_1=%~2\File_PDF_BU_%%~C.pdf"
                ) else if not defined copied_file_2 (
                    set "copied_file_2=%~2\File_PDF_BU_%%~C.pdf"
                )
            )
        ) else if not defined copied_file_1 (
            set "copied_file_1=|"
        ) else if not defined copied_file_2 (
            set "copied_file_2=|"
        )
    )
)

rem Delete old files in the archive folder
pushd "archive" || exit /b 3

for /f "skip=46 eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /a-d /o-d /b /s *.pdf 2^>nul') do (
    echo del  "%%~nxA"
    del "%%~A"
)

popd

rem Set attachments as global if set as file paths
endlocal & if not "%copied_file_1%" == "|" if not "%copied_file_2%" == "|" (
    set attachments="%copied_file_1%" "%copied_file_2%"
)
exit /b 0
```

This code follows the 5 specified aims. I stayed with the similar concept with the files rather than your idea of adding folders to the archive folder.

The `LocalDateTime` value stored in `ltd` is `YYYYMMDD-HHMMSSUUUU`, not the `YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.UUU` that your posted code has which conflicts with your posted summary. It can be changed if needed to match the correct pattern.

The code does 2 file copies at most, as it is tracked by the set variables of `copied_file_1` and `copied_file_2`. Those same 2 values are used for emailing of the 2 attachment files.

The mapped drive connection is done by use of `pushd` and the final use of `popd` will disconnect the drive. If the final use of `popd` is not used, then the drive may remain when the does script `exit`. So, `pushd` and `popd` require pairing to finish correct.

Your code copies a wildcard path to one filename. This code uses a `for` loop to copy each file and uses the original date stamp.